# jQuery Mobile, get backbutton working on iOS WebView

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, webview

I have created a simple jQuery Mobile page that you can access on http://appload.nu/UF/browse.php
Now, i am displaying this in a webview in a iOS app im working on, and want to make the page local (offline) to be able to keep the traffic down. The problem is, when the page is local, the back-button wont work. Now i've Googled about the problem, and found out that iOS webview have some issue with the property history.length that apparently the backbutton in jQuery Mobile uses somehow.

Now, how can i replace that property to make i work locally? I guess the basic problem is that the history-"class" doesn't work at all!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way is adding `data-add-back-btn="true"` to the page `div` like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="companies" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

Hint: You should clean up your code, put the jQuery Mobile external and post your configuration here. I'm not shure but I think you modified the original jQuery Mobile code to configure the app?! That's not the way it should be done.